# SSIS ETL vs RESTful Web Service vs Service Bus

Tags: database, web-services, ssis, etl, servicebus

I have databases across geographical locations and there is a need to synchronize databases near real time.
As per my information, SSIS ETL is suitable only for batch updates. Real time updates can be achieved by Web services or Service Bus.
Further, only SSIS ETL can handle larger volumes.
I am looking for limits on the velocity or volumes of data beyond where I can not think of Web services or Service Bus and trade-off analysis.
What is the approach suitable if the requirement is Larger Volumes and near Real Time updates.

Comment: Database replication may be an option too.

Comment: all the databases are not same, they have different purposes

Comment: So what are you going to synchronise?

Comment: some of the data being updated/added to one of the databases is also required to be updated/added in other databases

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/archive/2009/12/14/how-to-synchronize-multiple-geographically-distributed-sql-server-databases-using-sql-azure-data-sync.aspx?Redirected=true

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you take a look at the SqlBulkCopy class. It lets you do fast high volume inserts (just inserts, not updates) from .Net code.  So your code could grab a bunch of messages off the bus, and then insert them really quickly.

We are prototyping solutions to a problem similar to yours. SqlBulkCopy appears to be at least 10 times faster than normal insert statements, quite possibly more. It was the main, but not on only, factor in speeding up our process from taking 8 hours to taking only 15 minutes.